Tensorflow GPU dependencies installation
I have been learning neural network architecture and wanted to train some on my own
laptop (windows 10),
I have 2 gpus, (NVIDIA Geforce MX350[driver version: 31.0.15.4680], Intel(r) Iris(r) xe graphics[driver version: 30.0.101.2079])
please note, I do not have anaconda, I have installed python 3.10 on its own, with pycharm, and jupyter notebook
tensorflow doesn't seem to recognize the gpus when I'm run the following code
tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
Things i've tried:

update drivers (to the ones mentioned above) and run

used this video to install the latest version (2.16.1) of tensorflow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0

installed cuda tollkit and cuDNN (the versions which were compatible with the current versions of tensorflow and python 3.10, and added them to path) (also reinstalled tensorflow afterwards). I already had virtual studios installed...

The versions i installed can be seen in this pic
Image

I later found out that gpu support for windows 10 and above is limited to tensorflow versions 2.10 and below
for later versions i need to use WSL2
I do not intend to install WSL2 because it may take additional time to set up python and an ide in linux
As for tf 2.10
I would need to install the right version of cuda toolkit and cuDNN again
And perhaps learn what exactly bazel is, along with figuring out how to get the correct version of gcc (tf 2.10 needs 9.3.1, I have 6.3.0)
FINALLY:
I wanted to ask if there an easier way to install gpu supported tensorflow rather than what i've mentioned above

your question could be more to the point and is missing vital information: Which version of CUDA did you install, what NVIDIA driver version do you have, which tensorflow version(s) did you install/are trying to install? You mention "latest version", do you mean 2.16.1? Later you acknowledge that 2.10 is the latest version with gpu support on windows, so ahve you tried that version as well?

I've edited it. For trying out 2.10: I am trying to make sure if there isn't something else i'm missing, before getting cuda again, because it takes GBs of data and I would be limited by my network if it ended up not helping...

follow the step-by-step instructions in the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native instead of installing cuda using conda, you will need to download 11.2 from nvidia directly. Bazel, gcc, MSVC, clang are all only needed if you are trying to compile from source, which you don't need
